# Javascript document.getSelection

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the document.getSelection to select text I have entered in an text area for a WYSIWYG editor. It only works if you select text outside the text area though. I don't know if there is a way you can make it select text inside the text area?

Below is the text area for a WYSIWYG text editor:

```
<iframe id="editor" width="100%" height="400px" contentEditable="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the iframe document's selection:

```
var ifrDoc = document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document,
    sel = ifrDoc.getSelection();
```

Note that for Internet Explorer you need *document.selection.createRange()* instead of *document.getSelection()*.

Comment: And for browsers other than IE, you should use the standard DOM Level 2 HTML property `contentDocument` instead of `contentWindow.document`.

Comment: @bobince: I did realize I'd used a non-cross-browser compatible method in my example after writing the first line to be cross-browser compatible.  What can I say, other than I felt lazy after writing that first line? :-)